# Can every explicitly defined function be recursively defined?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I was learning about sequences and series in calculus, when I came across the function

$a_n = 3 + (-1)^n$,

which produced the sequence

$a_1=2$

$a_2=4$

$a_3=2$

$\ldots$

I couldn't come up with a recursive sequence for this, so I ask: is it possible to produce a recursive formula from an explicit one?

Comment: How about $a_n=6-a_{n-1}$, or $a_n=a_{n-2}$?

Comment: "*Is it possible to produce a recursive formula from an explicit one?*"  Sometimes it can be easy to do, but I would expect that it is not always possible to do.  It would largely depend on what terms appear in the closed form.

Comment: i thinks you can always write any function as a recursive one, but a proof would be heavy work.

Comment: If you learned that $a_n=c_1\cdot d_1^n+c_2\cdot d_2^n+c_k\cdot d_k^n$ with each $d_i$ distinct, you could reason that $(x-d_1)(x-d_2)\cdots(x-d_k)=b_0x^k-b_{1}x^{k-1}-\dots-b_{k}x^{0}$ implying $b_0a_n=b_1a_{n-1}+\dots+b_ka_{n-k}$ and then you can do some tedious algebra to find the specific initial conditions for your recursively defined sequence.  Similar tricks can be applied if you have terms of the form $p(n)d^n$ where $p(n)$ is a polynomial (*remembering that when $d=1$ the exponential term might be invisible*), but it becomes increasingly difficult to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

$$\quad{a_n = 3 + (-1)^n \to 3=a_n-(-1)^n\\n\mapsto n+1\\a_{n+1}=3+(-1)^{n+1}=\underbrace{a_n-(-1)^n}_{3}+(-1)^{n+1}\\a_{n+1}=a_n-(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}\\a_{n+1}=a_n+2\times(-1)^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

When you have a sequence for which the general term can be written as:
$$u_n= \sum_{k=1}^{K}{P_k(n).\alpha_k^n}$$
with $K$ a fixed integer and $P_k\in \mathbf{R}[X]$

Then you can find a relation between the term of $(u_n)$.

Let $d_k=deg(P_k)$ for all $k$, 
and let $Q=\prod_{k=1}^K{(X-\alpha_k)^{d_k}}$

If we write $Q$ as $Q=\sum_{i=1}^{d}{a_i.X^i}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{d}{a_i.u_{n+i}}=0$

To prove this we will use linea algebra:
Let $D$ be the operator which assign the sequence $(x_{n+1})$ to the sequence $(x_n)$.

We have $(D-\alpha.Id)(\alpha^n)=(0)$. (be careful here we write $(\alpha^n)$ for the sequence $(\alpha^n)_{n\in N}$ and $(0)$ for $(0)_{n\in N}$)

You can also prove that if $P$ is a polynomial, then $P(X+1)-P$ is a polynomial of degre $deg(P)-1$

Combining this two fact you get easily that: $(D-\alpha_k.Id)^{d_k}(P_k(n).\alpha_k^n)=(0)$

by suming everything you get the conclusion

To do thinq the other way you need to prove that proper space are in direct sum.